# How to get zoho books item image?

Tags: zohobooks

In Zoho books Items there are Product images, How we can get that images from API or any other way so we can push them into Other Service like Magento to any other.?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two API to get image of an item.

!https://www.zoho.com/books/api/v3/#Items_Get_an_item

you can get `image_document_id` from above API and replace it in below API to get an image.

[https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/documents/{image_document_id}](https://books.zoho.com/api/v3/documents/%7Bimage_document_id%7D)